# Image doesn't upload in custom module magento

Tags: image, php

I have created custom module in magento with image upload attribute. Image name was successfully stored in DB table. But image doesn't upload to the target folder.

I have tried with this following code. please show me "what am i doing wrong here"

```
 $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
 $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
 $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
 $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

 $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') .DS. 'foo'.DS ;
 $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);
```

Comment: Check if target folder has write permissions

Comment: i think you verified http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_create_pdf_upload_in_backend_for_own_module, for this, first check `print_r($_FILES);exit;` before the if condition `if(isset($_FILES['fileinputname']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['fileinputname']['tmp_name']))) {`, you'll find the key you used is wrong.

Comment: i have edit $path as $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/foo/'; Now its working Fine. THank you dudes

Comment: I have added my answer @Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edit file path like

```
 $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/foo/';
```

instead of

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') .DS. 'foo'.DS ;
```

That's All. Now Its working well

For further details please lookout [this post](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/to-add-image-upload-field-in-magento-admin-form/)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code,Below code works for me and just I give permission to directory where image will be stored

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') .DS. 'foo'.DS ;

      if(!is_dir($path))
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);

     $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);
```